# Windows Forms Application and Azure SQL

Tags: .net, winforms, azure-sql-database

I plan to create Windows Forms Application in Visual Basic 2010. I would like to use Azure SQL for storing data because of possibility to have access from more places, no need to have system administrator, to think about backup solutions and so on.

I have no experience with creating Web Applications, that's why I decided for Windows Forms Application.

I would like to know your opinion, if this is a big security risk and what of problems I can expect. For example the first problem is, that I wanted to allow one country on firewall, but I reached limit 128 firewall rules and this is not enough for me.

My second question:

If the solution "Windows Forms Application + Remote database" is OK, then which database do you recommend?

Thank you very much.

Comment: None, it's not OK if you don't know what you are doing. You'd have to create VPN connections from all clients to the server, create firewall exceptions for each client etc. And the performance would be atrocious due to network latency and bandwidth restrictions. It doesn't matter whether you use Amazon, Azure or Google, the same restrictions apply

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. If somebody has similar or different opinion, write it, please. It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: If the database has sensitive data (which most of the time it is), I would NOT do this. I would rather focus on learning how to create a Web application. Also, it doesn't matter if its in Azure or not.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see, that I was wrong. Thank you, that you prevent me from going wrong way.